# Is a US district court allowed to award punitive damages based on another state's law?

Tags: united-states, fraud, punitive-damages

Let's say

1. The plaintiff lives in Florida, US.
2. The defendant lives in California, US.

The plaintiff sues the defendant in a Texas District Court due to diversity jurisdiction. The case involves serious fraud and the plaintiff has no contractual relationship with the defendant.

Since California law has no cap for punitive damages, can the judge in Texas apply California law with regards to punitive damages?

If it is possible, could you cite some cases?

Comment: How would *TEXAS* of all places have jurisdiction? California sure has, but you need very special reasons for Texas to have.

Comment: @Trish It's in the middle? Maybe both parties have status on American Airlines..

Comment: "in the middle" is not a reason to have jurisdiction. To have jurisdiction, either the defendant has to live there, or it has to have another reason to have it.

Comment: @Trish I know, I was just being glib.
 The question is about what happens if the case is in a US District Court in a third party state; I don't know that it matters which three states are involved–unless the answer is" this would never happen."

Comment: @Trish It could be that the acts giving rise to the fraud took place in Texas.

Comment: @ohwilleke that would be the one and only way that jurisdiction would be there I could think of, but it needs to be more than just "via internet", yes. However, it's up to OP to specify how Texas *got* jurisdiction, becasue the defendant might file for wrong venue and get a dismissal.

Comment: @Trish If I were feeling creative I could imagine more ways it could come up. Until very recently, a company was subject to jurisdiction in any state where it had a brick and mortar office or an agent. If the defendant is an individual, "tag jurisdiction" is also another possibility.

Comment: @ohwilleke recently, several "I sue you in my state because you do internet stuff" cases were stricken down by the courts, sometimes even with the suing lawyer recommended for sanctions for filing in clearly the wrong jurisdiction.

Comment: @Trish the controlling rule for jurisdiction in Internet matters is usually where the actions were done or where the message was directed. For example, if the message were directed at making a statement about Texas real estate, from California, that was read by someone in Florida, Texas would probably be one state where jurisdiction would be proper.

Comment: @ohwilleke in the case of a commentator allegedly telling lies about a Washingtonian via youtube, Washington federal courts explicitly threw out the case as being filed in the wrong venue because the home state of the defendant would have been proper.

Comment: @Trish My complaint also has intellectual property related claims and some of the indirect infringes lives in Texas. Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: That is irrelevant for jurisdiction but that you need top be in federal system.

Comment: @Trish Do you have typos in your comment? I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: Copyright and Trademark are automatically and only cases in the federal system, so state courts are out, and indeed, state law might be out. **Indirect** impact on lives in an area is not establishing jurisdiction on itself. If something in Texas would give grounds for jurisdiction in the area, then it will be a 5th Circuit Case, never a Texas case. However, if the defendant is Californian, the default jurisdiction that for sure will work would be 9th Circuit.

Comment: Or to rephrase: In an IP case, Texas can't have Jurisdiction, as Copyright and Trademark are Federal only. If anything, 5th Circuit *might* have jurisdiction if Texas would be a jurisdiction if not for issue preclusion (Copyright and Trademark are). Betting on the case getting removed to 9th Circuit would however get rather good rates, unless there are really convincing reasons to get the case to 5th Circuit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Short Answer

At the level of generality presented in the question, it is impossible to know with any meaningful level of comfort, which state's laws regarding punitive damages caps will apply, even if there are prior precedents addressing a similar issue, since the determination is so dependent upon a rich set of relevant facts.

## Long Answer

**Does Federal Or State Law Apply?**

In a diversity case, under what is known as the [*Erie* doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erie_doctrine), after the U.S. Supreme Court case that established it, a federal district court sitting in diversity applies the substantive law of the state in which it is located (including its choice of law rules) and federal procedural law.

A variety of subsequent cases have clarified (or at least made more specific) what counts as substantive law, and what counts as procedural law. A [2018 law review article](https://scholarship.law.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3031&context=facpubs) (open access) uses a five page long flow chart to explain the rule. A simplified partial page flowchart regarding whether state or federal law applies can be found [here](https://legal.uworld.com/blog/legal/civ-pro-quick-tip-keeping-erie-from-getting-eerie/).

To cut a long analysis short, punitive damage limitations generally count as substantive law under this test.

So, the question of which state's law to apply to punitive damages caps in a diversity case brought in a U.S. District Court in Texas is precisely the same as the question faces by a Texas state court regarding which state's law to apply.

**Choice Of Law Analysis At The State Level**

In general, a state court (or a federal court sitting in diversity) applies the law of the state in which it is located unless a party argues that under choice of law principles that another state's law should apply, and that party shows that the law of the state whose law is proposed is different from the law of the state where the case is being tried.

Historically, there were rigid rules that provided that in particular kinds of cases, a particular state's law would apply. Some of those historical rules continue to have full force.

For example, the substantive real property law of the state where real property is located almost always applies.

But, in other cases, a more vague modern rule for choice of law applies. This is the rule that the law of the state with the most significant relationship to the issue to be decided should apply. Different issues in the same case may end up being governed by different laws as a result.

Among the factors to be considered in applying a most significant relationship test are:

1. The place where the event giving rise to the claim occurred.
2. The interest of the state where the person who was harmed resides in controlling the amount of compensation that the person harmed received.
3. The interest of the state where the person who caused the harm resides in encouraging or discouraging business activity that may hurt others.
4. The interest of the state where the insurance company paying some or all of the claim is located in not driving up insurance premiums.

The inquiry in this multi-factor balancing test is usually extremely fact intensive.

The practical effect of the most significant relationship test has been to make the ultimate decision less predictable and to make it more likely that a judge will decide that the forum state's law will apply. Under the historical rule, about two-thirds of requests to apply a non-forum state's law were granted. Under the modern rule, about one-third of such requests are granted.

A [law review article from 1987](https://scholarship.law.tamu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1254&context=facscholar) spells out the choice of law rules in Texas at the time which have probably become somewhat looser since that time that it was written. The article is James P. George, *Choice of Law Outline for Texas Courts*, 18 Tex. Tech L. Rev. 785 (1987). Available at: https://scholarship.law.tamu.edu/facscholar/255

A short article looking at the case law for choice of law cases with regard to punitive damages can be found [here](https://www.skadden.com/-/media/files/publications/2015/01/punitive-damages-and-choice-of-law-the-case-for-a.pdf). It opens by observing that:

> The United States Supreme Court has repeatedly acknowledged that while
> states are afforded discretion over the imposition of punitive
> damages, state law is still subject to "procedural and substantive
> constitutional limitations on these awards." *State Farm Mut. Auto.
> Ins. Co. v. Campbell*, 538 U.S. 408, 416 (2003). Relying on the Due
> Process Clause, the Court has provided some basis for determining
> which state's law applies to the punitive damages question and what
> conduct is subject to punitive liability. In Phillips Petroleum Co. v.
> Shutts, for example, the Supreme Court held that "for a State's
> substantive law to be selected in a constitutionally permissible
> manner, that State must have a significant contact or significant
> aggregation of contacts, creating state interests, such that choice of
> its law is neither arbitrary nor fundamentally unfair." *Phillips
> Petroleum Co. v. Shutts*, 472 U.S. 797, 818 (1985) (internal quotation
> marks and citation omitted). The Court has also made clear that
> "[e]lementary notions of fairness" require that a defendant must be
> given "fair notice" of what conduct is subject to punitive damages, as
> well as the severity of the penalty that may be imposed. *BMW of N.
> Am. v. Gore*, 517 U.S. 559, 574 (1996).

It also observes in an analysis that should be taken with a grain of salt, because it comes from a law firm that defends companies that are usually defendants in product liability cases rather than plaintiffs and is not written by a neutral party:

> a growing number of courts have begun to recognize that an analysis of
> the Restatement factors points to the application of defendants' home
> jurisdictions' laws to the issue of punitive damages. See, e.g.,
> Kirchman v. Novartis Pharm. Corp., No. 8:06- cv-1787-T-24-TBM, 2014 WL
> 2722483, at *4 (M.D. Fla. June 16, 2014) (applying the law of New
> Jersey to punitive damages claim because that state "is the place of
> injury-causing conduct," i.e., the state "where Novartis made its
> corporate decisions regarding the labeling, packaging and warning of
> the drugs, which Plaintiff alleges caused Mr. Kirchman's osteonecrosis
> of the jaw") (citation omitted); Williams v. Novartis Pharm. Corp., 15
> F. Supp. 3d 761, 768 (S.D. Ohio 2014) ("When a plaintiff seeks
> punitive damages against a manufacturer in a products liability case
> based on a 'failure to warn' theory, the focus, for purposes of a
> choice-of-law analysis, needs to be on the place where the defendant's
> alleged corporate misconduct occurred."); Braun, 2014 WL 345246, at *5
> (California law applied to punitive damages claims against infant
> sling manufacturer because defendant "designed its products in
> California" and therefore "all of the actions that would form the
> basis for punitive damages occurred there"); Dopson-Troutt v. Novartis
> Pharm. Corp., No. 8:06-CV-1708-T-24-EAJ, 2013 WL 3808205, at *4 (M.D.
> Fla. July 22, 2013) ("The Court agrees with the reasoning of the other
> courts who have found that" the Restatement principles "support
> applying New Jersey law to the punitive damages issue in this case"
> because "the basic policy underlying punitive damages is to punish and
> deter [the defendant], whose conduct occurred in New Jersey . . . .")
> (internal quotation marks and citation omitted). For example, in Irby,
> a Virginia plaintiff alleged that he developed osteonecrosis of the
> jaw after ingesting the drug Zometa, manufactured by Novartis. Irby,
> 2011 WL 5835414, at 2. The parties stipulated that Virginia law
> governed the plaintiff's compensatory claims for failure to warn,
> defective design, breach of implied warranty, negligence, and consumer
> fraud. They disagreed, however, on which state's law should govern
> plaintiff's punitive damages claim. Virginia law caps punitive damages
> at $350,000, while New Jersey law bars them completely in cases
> involving FDA-approved drugs. Plaintiff argued Virginia law should
> apply as the place of injury, while Novartis argued that the law of
> New Jersey should apply because its principal place of business is
> located in that state.

To some extent, these choice of law principles apply even in cases where there are arguably procedural rules that apply, rather than merely blindly following a federal procedure and state substantive distinction. Wikipedia's entry on the *Erie* doctrine [concludes in part by stating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erie_doctrine):

> Erie has gone in a newer and
> even more complicated direction than the previous controlling cases,
> and that instead of selecting either federal or state law for a case,
> the federal court may be required to somehow blend federal and state
> law, depending on the issue. This is quite frustrating for those who
> wish to have a black-letter rule that will point them to the answer.
> However, the possibility of blending in Erie does not open up an
> infinitude of possibilities.

But even in the context here where it is clear that state law rather than federal law applies, the determination of which state's law applies is itself involved and is frustratingly indeterminate.